# Formula for the Reeb field of the standard overtwisted contact form

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-fields, contact-geometry

I'm looking for a explicit formula for the Reeb field of the standard overtwisted form on $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is written in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho, \theta, z)$ as
$$
    \alpha = \cos(\rho)dz + \rho\sin(\rho)d\theta.
$$
I tried to calculate it myself but I got a mess of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in denominators, which doesn't make sense because the Reeb field should be uniquely defined everywhere.

I found [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381331/overtwisted-contact-forms-on-open-manifolds) where the OP gives a formula like what I'm looking for, but there's no suggestion of how one can obtain it, and the OP themselves say they are not sure if their calculations are correct.

Is there any references where one can find such calculations done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reeb vector field $R$ is characterized by
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha(R) & \equiv 1,\\
d\alpha(R,\cdot) & \equiv 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Write $R = f\partial_{\rho} + g \partial_{\theta} + h \partial_z$.
The first equality yields

$$
\cos \rho \, h + \rho \sin\rho \, g = 1.
$$

An easy calculation shows that $d\alpha = -\sin \rho \, d\rho\wedge dz + (\sin\rho + \rho\cos \rho) d\rho \wedge d\theta$.
To exploit $d\alpha(R,\cdot) = 0$, let us evaluate this equality on the frame $\{\partial_{\rho},\partial_{\theta},\partial_z\}$.

1. $d\alpha(R,\partial_{\rho})=0$ gives
   $$
   \sin \rho \, h  - (\sin\rho + \rho \cos\rho) g = 0, 
   $$
2. $d\alpha(R,\partial_{\theta}) = 0$ gives
   $$
   (\sin\rho + \rho \cos \rho) f = 0,
   $$
3. $d\alpha(R,\partial_z) = 0$ gives
   $$
   -\sin\rho\, f =0.
   $$

Hence, $f = 0$, and $h$ and $g$ satisfy
$$
\begin{cases}
\cos\rho\, h + \rho \sin \rho\, g &= 1 \\
\sin\rho \, h - (\sin\rho + \rho\cos \rho) g &= 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Solving for $(g,h)$ gives the desired result.
First we assume values of $\rho$ such that $cos\rho$ and $\sin\rho$ are not zero. Then the system yields
$$
\frac{1-\rho \sin \rho\, g}{\cos\rho} = h = \frac{\sin\rho+\rho\cos\rho}{\sin\rho}g,
$$
from which we obtain
$$
g =\frac{\sin\rho}{\rho + \cos\rho\,\sin\rho} = \frac{2\sin\rho}{2\rho+\sin(2\rho)},
$$
where we used the identity $\sin(2\rho) = 2\sin\rho\,\cos\rho$. We now solve for $h$ and get
$$
h = \frac{2\sin\rho + 2\rho\cos\rho}{2\rho+\sin(2\rho)}.
$$
Thus
$$
R = \frac{2}{2\rho + \sin(2\rho)}\left(\sin(\rho)\partial_\theta + (\sin\rho + \rho\cos\rho)\partial_z\right),
$$
for $\rho \neq 0$. Since $\alpha$ is a $C^\infty$ form, the Reeb field is smooth. Due to unicity, all it takes to determine $R$ at the origin is to take the limit when $\rho \to 0$. Hence
$$
R = \begin{cases}
\left(\frac{2}{2\rho + \sin(2\rho)}\right)[\sin(\rho)\partial_\theta + (\sin\rho + \rho\cos\rho)\partial_z], &\text{ for } \rho \neq 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\partial_\theta + \partial_z, &\text{ for } \rho = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $d\alpha = -\sin \rho \, d\rho\wedge dz + (sin\rho + \rho\cos \rho) d\rho \wedge d\theta$? Also, the first equality in the system is $\cos\rho h +\rho\sin\rho g = 1$.

This is the approach I tried, but solving the system for $h$ and $g$ gives answers in terms of secants and cosecants, which are not defined everywhere, hence my uncertainties about my calculations.

Comment: @usbc Obviously you're right, I did not check my computations. I'm going to put this on paper to see if I can find a nicer form form the solution than one using secants or cosecants.

Comment: I went over my calculations again, and using some rather elementary trigonometrical identities I was able to obtain the same result as in the link in my question. The only thing I'm not very confident about is how the Reeb field behaves at the origin.

Comment: @usbc Great. You can edit my answer and transform it into a community wiki answer if you want!

Comment: @usbc Actually, I have a doubt on the very final equality. How is defined $\partial_{\theta}$ when $\rho=0$?

Comment: If you put $\rho=0$ into the system you get $h=1$, but $g$ can be anything because the only relation it must satisfy is $0 + 0g = 0$. On the other hand, the term $\frac{2\sin(\rho)}{2\rho + \sin(2\rho)}\partial_\theta$ goes to $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\theta$ as $\rho$ goes to $0$, so this must be its value at the origin, because the Reeb field is smooth.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore My point is that the vector field $\partial_{\theta}$ is not well defined on the vertical axis $\rho=0$, right? That's the thing with cylindrical coordinates: they are defined on $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{\text{vertical axis}\}$.
In the plane, polar coordinates are not defined at the origin. This is similar

Comment: @Didier, yes, you're right., polar coordinates don't map the origin, and there's no way to extend $\partial_\theta$ smoothly at $0$. One would need to use another set of coordinates around the origin. The calculations I made in the linked question were basically the same as usbc did here, though I realize now the part about the origin doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @DouglasFinamore Yes. I would have expected something like $\partial_z$ along the vertical axis, so that the singularity of cylindrical coordinates wouldn't matter. Maybe there is a computational error somewhere? Note that along the vertical axis (*i.e* when $\rho=0$), $\alpha(\partial_z)=1$ and $d\alpha(\partial_z,\cdot) = 0$!

Comment: My intuition at first was that $R$ should be $\partial_z$ at the origin. I even said that in the question on MO, though I didn't realized my mistake at the time. Every paper and book I can remember reading uses the formula above for the standard overtwisted form on $\Bbb R^3$ without paying any attention to what happens at the origin, but I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be just $dz$ at the $z$-axis. I'll write $\alpha$ down in cartesian coordinates and try to calculate the Reeb field at the origin to see if it provides any insight.